# Empty angle brackets in template definition

Tags: c++, templates

This question was at the interview:
*Does this code causes any compile/linking errors and why so?*

```
template <int T> void f();
template <> void f<0>() {}

void test() 
{
    f<1>();
}
```

Please explain the behaviour. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Linking error, you need `template <int T> void f() { }`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
template<> void f<0>() {}
```

is specialization of function template for argument `0`, if you call `f<0>()` this version of function will be called.

This code is incorrect, it cause linking errors, since there is no specialization for `f<1>` and template version of function is not `defined`.

Comment: Why <int T> statement was skipped in the definition? Is that possible?

Comment: @Netherwire yes, since it's specialization, `template<>` points, that it's full specialization of function.

Comment: so it should include `template <int T> void f() { } ` to cover all cases, right? Or just `template <> void f<1>() {}` to define another special case. I checked this.

Answer (score 8):

It will compile (all the code is gramatically valid) but will fail at link stage.

This is because `template <int T> void f();` is declared but *not* defined, the <0> specialisation *is* defined but that makes no odds to you since you're not instantiating it.

Actually, it *would* be possible for the <0> specialisation to contain syntax errors and the program *would* still compile without error! This is because formally, templates are only compiled if they are used. (I wouldn't expect a candidate to have the presence of mind during interview conditions to point that out.)

Comment: "it would be possible for the <0> specialisation to contain syntax errors and the program would still compile without error!" - true, but only with lax compilers. Other compilers won't have that.

Comment: No, it's part of the standard.

Comment: I'd argue that even if that is part of the standard, a <0> specialization containing syntax errors only _might_ compile; it can't be guaranteed. If it contains an extra unmatched `}` syntax error, the compiler may have trouble determining where the function definition was supposed to end, causing it to parse incorrectly down the line.

Answer (score 4):

It will compile because compiler can see a declaration for a generic template. There is a fully specialized template for 0 also. But we are calling it for 1, which will try to invoke the generic template, but since linker cannot find any definition for the general template, the program will show linker error.

Soloution

```
template <int T> void f();
template <> void f<0>() {}
template <int T> void f() { }


void test() 
{
  f<1>();
}
```